# I am receiving 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' errors but cannot find the source

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have these four tables that represent a hardware store:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tools;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS departments;

CREATE TABLE departments (
    name PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tools (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    tool_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    tool_price DECIMAL(5, 2),
    tool_department VARCHAR(250),
    FOREIGN KEY (tool_department) REFERENCES departments(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone_number INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    customer_first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    customer_last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    customer_phone_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tool_purchased TEXT NOT NULL,
    item_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (tool_purchased) REFERENCES tools(tool_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_first_name) REFERENCES customers(first_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_last_name) REFERENCES customers(last_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_phone_number) REFERENCES customers(phone_number) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I am trying to insert this data into my tables:

```
INSERT INTO tools(tool_name, tool_price, tool_department)
VALUES
    ('Snow shovel', 16.50, 'Home & Garden'),
    ('Work light', 29.99, 'Electrical'),
    ('Wheelbarrow', 89.99, 'Home & Garden'),
    ('Pipe Wrench', 18.99, 'Plumbing'),
    ('Pipe Cutter', 36.36, 'Plumbing'),
    ('Rake', 15.45, 'Home & Garden');

INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name, phone_number)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Smith', 1111111111),
    ('Jane', 'Doe', 2222222222);

INSERT INTO transactions(customer_id, customer_first_name, customer_last_name, customer_phone_number, tool_purchased, item_quantity)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Smith', 1111111111, 'Work light', 1),
    (1, 'John', 'Smith', 1111111111, 'Pipe Cutter', 2),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 2222222222, 'Snow shovel', 3),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 2222222222, 'Work light', 1),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 2222222222, 'Pipe Wrench', 1),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 2222222222, 'Pipe Cutter', 1),
    (1, 'John', 'Smith', 1111111111, 'Wheelbarrow', 3);
```

However, I am getting these errors back:

> `Error: near line 1: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`
> `Error: near line 15: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

Comment: Don't you need to insert 'departments' before you attempt to insert tools referring to that department?

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please do not deface posts. Please do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the type of column `name` in table `departments`! Must be `VARCHAR(250)` like in table `tools` (FK).

```
CREATE TABLE departments (
    name VARCHAR(250) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Correct departments table and insert department in it in order to reference tools to this dept. You cannot reference a tool to department that does not exist yet. Also read docs about column types `TEXT` and `VARCHAR`.

Comment: SQLite does not need the data types:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=99f82ec6c5ca62fedcebec2dc14559c4 In fact you can use anything as a data type: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=0da1e70b1b2207f446de85108dbd7ad8, even nothing.